# While loop cannot be not terminated with eof

Tags: c, linux, file, buffer, eof

```
char buf_in()
{
    if(read_pos==16)
    {
        read_pos=0;
        read(fd_in,buffer_in,16);
    }
    return buffer_in[read_pos++];
}

void buf_out(char data)
{
    if(write_pos==16)
    {
        write_pos=0;
        write(fd_out,buffer_out,16);
    }
    buffer_out[write_pos++]=data;
}
```

```
int main()
{
    fd_in=open("input.txt",O_RDONLY);
    fd_out=open("result.txt",O_WRONLY|O_CREAT,0666);
    char ch;
    while((ch=buf_in())!= EOF)
    {
        buf_out(ch);
    }
    close(fd_in);
    close(fd_out);
    return 0;
}
```

These are my codes, and when I look at the result.txt, it looks like the content of the input file and bunch of nulls and the content of input file appears again. So it never ends. What is the problem of my code? Thanks.

Comment: If you want `while((ch=buf_in())!= EOF)` to work, you must program the function `buf_in` to return `EOF` when a read fails due to reaching end-of-file. However, you did not do this. You are instead ignoring the return value of `read`, so you will not notice when end-of-file is reached. Also, a `char` is not guaranteed to be able to represent the value `EOF`. Use `int` instead, if you want to be sure that the data type can represent the value `EOF`.

Comment: In addition to what Andreas mentioned, unless input files are a multiple of 16, `buf_in` must remember the returned length of `read` and return `EOF` when that is exceeded on the last call. That is, at some point, instead of reading 16 bytes, we'll read less (e.g. 7). So, on the last read, after filling the buffer, `buf_in` must return [only] 7 valid chars and EOF for the 8th.

Comment: Please show us the definition of the variables `read_pos` and `write_pos`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `while((ch=buf_in())!= EOF)` to work, you must program the function `buf_in` to return `EOF` when a read fails due to reaching end-of-file. However, you did not do this. You are instead ignoring the return value of `read`, so you will not notice when end-of-file is reached.

Also, a `char` is not guaranteed to be able to represent the value `EOF`. Use `int` instead, if you want to be sure that the data type can represent the value `EOF`.

You appear to be under the impression that `EOF` is the character code of a character that appears at the end of the file. However, that is not the case. The value `EOF` is not a character code. It is a special value that is returned by functions such as [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar), to indicate that no character was retrieved. The function `read` will not necessarily return the value `EOF` to indicate end-or-file or an error. It uses a different mechanism to report this. It will return the number of bytes successfully read, or `-1` on error. The value `EOF` may be equal to the value `-1` on some platforms, but you cannot rely on this.

In order to solve the problems mentioned above, you could rewrite the function `buf_in` like this:

```
int buf_in( void )
{
    if ( read_pos == 16 )
    {
        read_pos = 0;
        if ( read( fd_in, buffer_in, 16 ) == -1 )
            return EOF;
    }
    return (unsigned char)buffer_in[read_pos++];
}
```

The cast to `unsigned char` is necessary so that it is guaranteed that all character codes are distinguishable from the value `EOF`.

However, this would not properly handle the case of `read` only reading between `1` and `15` bytes, instead of `16` bytes.

Therefore, it would probably be best to add an additional variable `ssize_t bytes_read` and to initialize this variable to `0`. Afterwards, you can use the following code:

```
int buf_in( void )
{
    if ( read_pos == bytes_read )
    {
        read_pos = 0;
        bytes_read = read( fd_in, buffer_in, 16 );
        if ( bytes_read == -1 )
            return EOF;
    }
    return (unsigned char)buffer_in[read_pos++];
}
```

Note that you must also change the variable declaration

```
char ch;
```

in the function `main` to

```
int ch;
```

because we have changed the return value of the function `buf_in` to `int`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But is there anyway to keep char buf_in?

Comment: @ECH: On platforms on which `char` is unsigned, you will be unable to represent the value `EOF` in a `char`, so you will have to use `int` instead. On platforms on which `char` is signed (which is most platforms), you will be unable to distinguish the special value `EOF` from an actual character code if you use `char`. Therefore, you do have to use `int` instead of `char`, if you want your program to work reliably.